# Action takes 2 clicks instead of 1 in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

My reset button takes 2 clicks to reset the position of puppy instead of 1. I'm wondering where I went wrong. Also, when I start clicking the tapButton again after resetting, the puppy goes back to the position it was at before the reset. Any ideas on why that would happen?

I'm pretty new so I probably put some things in the wrong place.

```
var tapsCount = 0
var countdownNumber = 10
var Timer : NSTimer = NSTimer()


class ViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var puppy: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var secondsLeft: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tapsCounter: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var currentHighScore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var colon: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Banner: ADBannerView!

@IBOutlet weak var endMessage: UILabel!
@IBAction func tapButton() {
    if tapsCount == 0 {
        Timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("UpdateTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    } else {

    }
    tapsCount = tapsCount+1
    tapsCounter.text = "\(tapsCount)"

    if countdownNumber<0 {
        secondsLeft.text = ""
        tapsCounter.text = ""
    } else {


  //-------moving the puppy----------------------


        UIView.animateWithDuration(0, delay: 100, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
            self.puppy.alpha = 1
            self.puppy.center.y = self.puppy.center.y + 1  //this will change Y position of your imageView center every time you press button
            }, completion: nil)

        if self.puppy.center.y >= 131 {
            puppy.center.y = 131
        }
        if self.puppy.center.y <= -41 {
            puppy.center.y = -41
        }
    }
       }

@IBAction func resetButton() {
    tapsCount = 0
    countdownNumber = 10
    colon.text = ":"
    Timer.valid
    secondsLeft.text = "10"
    tapsCounter.text = "0"
    endMessage.text = ""
    Timer.invalidate()

    puppy.frame = CGRectMake( 187, 325, puppy.frame.size.width, puppy.frame.size.height );


}


func UpdateTimer() {
    secondsLeft.text = String(countdownNumber--)
    if countdownNumber == (-1) {
        secondsLeft.text = ""
        colon.text = ""
        var finalScore = tapsCount
        var highest = currentHighScore.text
        tapsCounter.text = ""


    } else if countdownNumber<(0) {
        Timer.invalidate()
        secondsLeft.text = ""
        tapsCounter.text = ""
    } else {
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {

    Banner.hidden = true
    Banner.delegate = self
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

    secondsLeft.text = String(countdownNumber)
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.




}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    Banner.hidden = false
}

}
```

The main part of the code that contains the reset button is here:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

 @IBAction func resetButton() {
    tapsCount = 0
    countdownNumber = 10
    colon.text = ":"
    Timer.valid
    secondsLeft.text = "10"
    tapsCounter.text = "0"
    endMessage.text = ""
    Timer.invalidate()

    puppy.frame = CGRectMake( 187, 325, puppy.frame.size.width, puppy.frame.size.height );


  }
}
```

Comment: That `delay: 100` is likely problematic...

Comment: Which event you have set for button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `puppy.frame` this way:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.puppy.frame = CGRectMake( 187, 325, self.puppy.frame.size.width, self.puppy.frame.size.height );
}
```

Comment: Check this sample project: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=97544243435684077587 @adman